# Strings or hypertext Onclick event WxWidgets

Tags: c++, html, events, hyperlink, wxwidgets

so, here's the deal. I have some program who needs to call some event when i click on a word or phrase. I was thinking on html hypertext but not sure. My question is, how should i edit hyperlink event to call any function. Any other suggest will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like a good idea to turn every word in a text in a hyper link. If you really want to do this, you can just use [wxHtmlWindow](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_html_window.html) and handle its `EVT_HTML_LINK_CLICKED` event.

But a better idea would probably be to use either a plain [wxTextCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_text_ctrl.html) or [wxRichTextCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_rich_text_ctrl.html), depending on the kind of contents you want to show, handle `EVT_LEFT_UP` in it and use [HitTest() method](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_text_ctrl.html#ad48c6f67afe17085c67231379bba2d7e) to find out where did the click occur exactly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the link: wxRichTextCtrl::BeginURL
2. Bind your handler to the event: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html#overview_events_bind
3. In handler, check which mouse event: wxTextUrlEvent::GetMouseEvent
4. In handler check which URL clicked: wxTextUrlEvent::GetURLStart
5. If all OK, call required function.